# Changing the layer when the filter request value gets changed in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wfs, filter

I am currently stuck with the example of [OpenLayers Vector WFS get Feature](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html).
The layer of the map doesn't get updated when I try to set the filter to a dynamic variable.

I shortened some of the example code:

```
public filteredRequest$ = new BehaviorSubject<Filter>(undefined)

constructor(public filterService: filterService)
 {
  this.filteredRequest$.subscribe(() => {
   this.featureRequest()
 }
```

the variable receives the changed value dynamically --> working

```
const vectorSource = new VectorSource();
const vector = new VectorLayer({source: vectorSource});
const map = new Map({
  layers: vector
  target: document.getElementById('map'),
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 12,
  }),
});

//generate the feature request with filter
featureRequest(){
const featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
  srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
  featureNS: 'http://openstreemap.org',
  featurePrefix: 'osm',
  featureTypes: ['water_areas'],
  outputFormat: 'application/json',
  filter: likeFilter('name', this.filteredRequest$)
});

// then post the request and add the received features to a layer
fetch('https://url/geoserver/wfs', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest),
})
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (json) {
    vectorSource.clear()
    const features = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
  });
}
```

Here it's somehow not working anymore:

The map gets the initial value, and the layer is displayed, but the layer doesnt get changed if the variable changes it's value.
It's only "working" if i click e.g. the refresh button of the browser...

Any ideas?

Comment: When the variable changes, you have to do new `fetch` and clear `vectoSource` before adding new features.

Comment: i added vectorSource.clear() right? and you mean a new fetch everytime the observable variable gets a new value?

Comment: Yes, it does not happen automatically.

Comment: it's working, thank you very much  :) - for all others struggling with that: i updated the code above adding a function called featureRequest() and subscribed to the variable filteredRequest$ and called the function.

Comment: You can publish answer to your own question, so it will be clear that problem was resolved.